# How to restrict Windows user from closing a Java process?

Tags: java

There is a client who would like to install a custom Java application on his business owned computers, However, he doesn't want to give the ability for the limited users to close the application, even from Windows Task Manager.

The purpose of the application is to monitor some specific resources and do several tasks silently. The users of these computers will be aware of this software and what it does exactly.

I couldn't find a way to do this by using the Java programming language! Is it possible or it's mainly related to Windows users' permissions and capabilities system?

Comment: Why would you want that? Your application should always close gracefully when the user wants it to. If they don't want your program running, it shouldn't be running.

Comment: @Tharwen, not true, e.g. what if the user was an employee using some company's computer. It's upto the company what they want running on the pc.

Comment: @Ash Then why does the employee have access to task manager?

Comment: Ok , My program is a count app its very important to make my app uncloseable , you can see such things in program like CafeAgent.exe

Comment: @Tharwen, they might not but task manager isn't the only way of stopping a program. The point is there are times when this is appropriate.

Comment: @Tharwen , I don't want to disable task manger , It's good tool to close hung apps :)

Comment: Thanks @Ash Burlaczenko You understand what I want to do :)

Comment: @Ash and my point is that anyone who has been deemed responsible for what's running on their computer (by being given access to tools for managing that) should always be able to control what's running on their computer.

Comment: Also, Nashwan, what do you mean by 'count app'?

Comment: mmmm , It's like Cafe Management Software counts the time and send info about the PC .

Comment: So wouldn't it be better to just store when the program is started, then calculate the difference between that and the system time when you need it?

Comment: Yes it's a good idea , but my app also send a small screenshots to the server to see what the user is doing , so I can't let ther close the program .

Comment: We're going in circles here, but in my mind there's nothing more to it - **Anyone who can't be trusted to be able to close the process should not be able to close the process.** Hiding the program and making it immortal is just patching over that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run it as a Windows service, started by the Administrator. That way, users won't be able to close the process as they do not have high enough privileges.

Refer to http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp for a fantastic wrapper that you can use.

For a short tutorial, look at http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/launch-win.html

Comment: It's looks interesting , Can you explane how to use it ? and is it easy to install it on the computer ?

Comment: All you need is to know how to execute the `sc` command. Have a read at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: There's numerous tutorials available, some on the site, some in the downloads. I use it often to install a Java application as a Windows Service using standard installation software.  Basically, it wraps the Java runtime as a Windows service that executes your application.

Comment: I've added a direct link to the Windows service tutorial.

Comment: Thank You , Iam reading about it now , It's looks like what I want .

Comment: Excellent - I've seen it used quite often and have only heard great things about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do such a thing in the program itself. It is more of a system level thing. Try launching the JVM (`java.exe`) as a System process.

Comment: There is nothing called "You Can't" Iam sure there is a native way to do it !

Comment: Sure, there is a thing called "You Can't" when it comes to basic OS security features, such as a process not being able to elevate itself to some kind of invincible state, where the OS cannot kill it anymore.

Comment: This answer is correct.  If there isn't a way to do it, there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192 in case you want to learn how to execute the `sc` command to create a Windows service.

Comment: Ok , see this screenshout it's for program called CafeAgent , I try to close it by all ways I read about ( pskill , proesshacker .. etc )

Answer (score 0):

Having something unclosable and invisible sounds unethical, but I'd imagine it does have legitimate uses. If it is for something worthwhile like protecting vulnerable people online etc. then they should probably not have task manager access in the first place, preventing them from stopping the JVM. Consider user privileges over attempting to code around corners.